# auto mapping properties from two classes with third class using automapper

Tags: automapper, automapping, automapper-3, automapper-5

I have two classes, say ClassA and ClassB, and I want to map them with ClassC. How can I do it?

ClassA has only 1 property and ClassB has 5 properties. ClassC has 6 properties.

Situation is something as below:

```
Public ClassC MapRequest(classA id, ClassB someProperties){
    _mapper.Map<ClassC>(id);
    _mapper.Map<Classc>(someProperties);

    retrun type of ClassC;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is overload of `Map` method available.

```
var objClassC = _mapper.Map<ClassA, ClassC>(id);

// You need to pass above instance to next call.
_mapper.Map<ClassB, ClassC>(someProperties, objClassC );
```

Hope this helps.